# How to set a REPO to be the default in Azure DevOps (GIT)

Tags: azure-devops

I have an existing project and added to that multiple new Repos.  I also deleted the existing Repo that had the name of the Project.

Of the new Repos, I want one of them to be the default repo.  How can I set that, or is it only by convention that the Default one has the name of the Project.